# como puedo cambiar una palabra por asteriscos (*)

Tags: java

```
   String str[]={"hola"};
   String str1;
   str1=str1.replaceAll(str[i], "*");
            System.out.println(str1);
```

y la respuesta me sale * , porque como puse un solo asterisco sustituye la palabra por uno solo pero yo quiero que me salga **** por que la palabra "hola" tiene 4 caracteres.

> entonces en el replaceAll no se como poner para que me sustituya a toda la palabra por asteriscos...

Comment: Si deseas usar ese codigo a manera de simular un campo de contraseñas entonces te recomiendo simplemente usar un componente llamado JPasswordField de Java.awt, ese componente tiene directamente aquello que estas buscando, por lo que si tu idea es usar un JTextField y simular en el este comportamiento, seria mejor simplemente reemplazarlo por un JPasswordField, en caso de que solo sea por experimentar... ya hay buenas respuestas al respecto...

Comment: Ooops, siempre los confundo!, creo que enrealidad me refiero al paquete javax.swing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espero poderte ayudar, este código seria:

```
String str = "hola";
String str1 = "";
for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
    str1 = str1 + "*";
}
System.out.println(str1);
```

Comment: si, gracias al final lo resolví de esa manera.

Comment: Se considera de baja calidad responder solo con codigo, porfavor leer. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar esto

```
str1 = str.replaceAll(".", "*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez la mejor alternativa es mostar n veces el asterísco, donde n es la longitud del texto en lugar de ir sustituyendo cada carácter por *:

```
int n = str.length();
str1 = "*".repeat( n );
```

Comment: Deberías indicar en que versiones de Java funciona.

Comment: [En Java 11](https://howtodoinjava.com/java11/repeat-string-n-times/)

Answer (score 0):

Antoni ya te dio una posible solución, al utilizar el método replaceALL(), lo que haces es tomar toda la palabra y convertirla en un *. es por eso que cuando utilizas

```
str1=str.replaceAll(str, "*");
```

toma toda la palabra que esta en str y lo transforma a una *, asi cómo lo tienes se puede utilizar para tranformar algún caracter o palabra de una oración como en este ejemplo:

```
   String str = "hola como estas";
   String str1;
   str1=str.replaceAll("como", "*");
            System.out.println(str);
            System.out.println(str1);
```

Resultado:

```
Hola como estas
Hola * estas
```